# Java - how to get subclass method to superclass

Tags: java

I have a subclass that extends a superclass, and the method that I have written in the subclass (Get Insurance Cost) is not being recognised by the superclass. When the button is pressed to Calculate the insurance cost, nothing happens, and in the superclass, the words **getinsurance** are underlined in red - meaning that it cannot locate the method.

```
if (arg.equals("Calculate Insurance")) {
    String valueStr = insurancevaluetextField.getText();
    value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);

    add (insuranceDisplayArea); 
    insuranceDisplayArea.setText("The insurance charge for your package is:  $"
            + df.format(getInsurancecost()) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429114/calling-methods-of-parent-component-in-java

Comment: You don't have to override `getCharge` if you are happy with the superclass definition. Also, it's getInsurancecost not getInsurance fyi

Comment: If your super class needs the information about the insurance cost, then the right place for the field (and its getter and setter) is the super class, not the sub class. Seems to be a design issue that you really should reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Super-classes cannot run methods from their subclass. However, a super-class method can be called form a subclass. Consider redesigning your classes.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I might do that please? I have been stuck on this for over a week and need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggest that you got it backwards:
It is possible to use non-private methods of the superclass in the subclass
NOT methods of the subclass in the superclass. You have to create an instance of your subclass in order to use its methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you can declare your class `Parcel` as `abstract` you can add

```
public abstract double getInsurancecost();
```

This way your superclass is gonna be able to call the method defined by it's children.

Comment: Thanks, @Joshua, I've tried your recommendation, but i have an error in the ParcelTest file where I have:                    
      Parcel parcel = new Parcel();                            "Parcel is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

Comment: If you use abstract you can no longer instanciate Parcel... You have to use a Parcel p = new InsuredParcel(); but i don't think any of this is gonna help you solve you real problem : application design.